# How to use/setup Quick Fixes for vscode (c++)?

Tags: c++, syntax-error

How do I use or setup **Quick Fix** in vscode for c++ scripts?
[image]

The error in the above code is that **strcpm** is supposed to be **strcmp**. When I right-click/**Ctrl+.** on the error, the option for Quick Fix is there which expands to:
[image]

I assume there is supposed to be more? the suggested resolutions perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

Im running into the same problem basically most other IDEs provide some sort of suto fix feature. Like for example if you accidentally used the wrong library command however vscode doesnt have a ything built in... im looking at the extension sonar lint right now dont know where it would lead. I also heard of clangd. I dont know how to set it up however.

Comment: Please do not answer a post with "I'm having this problem too". Instead, if you have more detail about what the problem might be, add it as a comment to the original question

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32557339)